# Changing language from Persian to English in QGIS

Tags: qgis, internationalization

How can I change the language in QGIS from Persian to English?

Answer (score 5):

You can read [this part of the official QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#general-settings).

<kbd>**Settings**</kbd> menu > <kbd>**Options**</kbd> > <kbd>**General**</kbd> tab

> **Override System Locale**
>
> By default, QGIS relies on your Operating System configuration to set language and manipulate numerical values. Enabling this group allows you to customize the behavior.
>
> Select from `User interface translation` the language to apply to the GUI

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer myself, please watch this YouTube video:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj69aaX1IH4AhUI_7sIHbyYCzEQwqsBegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRJAt99BNXRE&usg=AOvVaw21VPUbhzG-l3E_FeVNztcK

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).